# Ando en busca de una guía para un trabajo practico donde debo realizar un juego

Tags: python

Tengo una función que definir: me dan un **".txt"** que tiene productos, cada producto tiene dos valores, uno económico y otro premium (en total son **84** productos). Lo que me pide hacer la actividad es cargar esta lista de productos del **".txt"** para luego usarlo en otras funciones, tal que me quede así:

```
[["arroz",300,600],["televisor",800,1200],["gorra",700,900],["mouse",550,790]...]
```

Lo cual no logro poder realizar del todo. Pude realizar dos cosas pero no puedo complementarlas:

entre ellas **la primera**, que logre sacar el `"\n"` pero no puedo anidar los productos y me quedan como `str` :

```
def lectura():
    archivo = open("productos.txt","r")
    listaProductos = []

    for renglon in archivo.readlines():
        listaProductos.append(renglon)
        with open('productos.txt') as stop_word:
             lineas = [linea.strip() for linea in stop_word]

print(lineas)
archivo.close()
```

y **la segunda**, donde pude armar los productos como listas pero luego no logro que todos los productos queden en una sola lista:

```
def lectura():
    archivo=open("productos.txt","r")
    lista_productos=[]
    for renglon in archivo.readlines():
        x=renglon.split(",")
        lista=[x[0],int(x[1]),int(x[2])]
```

¿Cómo hacer para que quede así?: *[["arroz",300,600],["televisor",800,1200],["gorra",700,900], ...]*

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugerimos revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Cambia la última línea por `lista.append([x[0],int(x[1]),int(x[2])])`

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Si colocás el mouse sobre la etiqueta [programación-bajo-nivel], te darás cuenta que Python _no es un lenguaje de bajo nivel_ :) Además, pon en el título el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo, porque tal cual como está, suena a que quieres que se te haga la tarea. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente lo tienes todo pero desperdigado... A ver, por pasos:

- Para leer un archivo puedes usar el builtin `open()`, si lo llamas sin mas como en `archivo = open("productos.txt","r")` debes siempre cerrar el archivo llamando a `close()` cuando termines con el. Lo haces en el primer código pero no el segundo.

  De todas formas, es mejor si usas la cláusula `with` para abrir el archivo haciendo uso de los gestores de contexto, en cuyo caso el archivo será cerrado automáticamente al terminar el bloque y no necesitas llamar a `open()` explícitamente.
- Para eliminar los saltos de linea puedes efectivamente usar `str.strip()`, aunque mejor aun, puedes usar `str.rstrip()` que solo aplica la eliminación al final de la cadena, que es lo que te interesa. Ambos métodos, si no se les pasa ningún argumento retorna una nueva cadena eliminando los conocidos como "whitespace characters", que incluye `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, etc, del princio/final de la cadena.
- Para separar el producto de sus precios (las columnas de tu .csv), puedes usar tal como haces en la segunda función `str.split()`. Basta con que apliques `split` a la salida del método `str.strip()` para conseguir ambas cosas, bien usando variables intermedias:

  ```
    linea_producto = linea.rstrip()
    datos_producto = linea_producto.split(",")
  ```

  o directamente encadenando la llamada:

  ```
    datos_producto = linea.rstrip().split(",")
  ```
- Para agregar todos los productos a la misma lista, casi lo tienes en tu segundo código, basta con añadir tu lista generada para cada linea con `lista=[x[0],int(x[1]),int(x[2])`] a `lista_productos` usando `list.append`.

En definitiva, algo como:

```
def lectura():
    productos = []
    with open('productos.txt') as archivo:
        for linea in archivo:
            producto = linea.rstrip().split(",")
            productos.append([producto[0], int(producto[1]), int(producto[2])])
    return productos
```

---

Tu archivo realmente es un archivo csv sin cabecera, [Python tiene un modulo especifico para leer, parsear y generar este tipo de archivos en su biblioteca estándar](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/csv.html). Dado que es una tarea, supongo que querrán que trabajes con el archivo "manualmente", pero:

```
import csv

def lectura():
    with open('productos.txt', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
        return [[row[0], int(row[1]), int(row[2])] for row in csv.reader(csvfile)]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! me sirvió completamente tu ayuda!!!